# Get unique node from xml file if nodes are repeated

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

```
<TestCase name="TestCase2" UID="8eb5d202-1559-47b3-b39e-21e46d0bc9d2" State="Checked" DataSourceId="">
    <TestModule name="Recording1" State="Checked" UID="2">
    </TestModule>
    <TestModule name="Recording1" State="Checked" UID="2">
    </TestModule>
    <TestModule name="Recording1" State="Checked" UID="2">
    </TestModule>
  </TestCase>
```

In above xml i have multiple nodes with same name and UID,Need to insert first node inbetween second and third but it fails because l_NodeToAppend  and l_targetNode are same how should i identify the node if nodes are repeated.

```
XmlNode l_NodeToAppend = null;
foreach (XmlNode i in e.SourceModels)
{
    l_NodeToAppend = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//TestModule[@UID='{0}']", i.Attributes["UID"].Value));
    if (l_NodeToAppend != null)
        break;
}

XmlNode l_targetNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//TestModule[@UID='{0}']", e.TargetModel.Attributes["UID"].Value));

l_targetNode.ParentNode.InsertBefore(l_NodeToAppend, l_targetNode);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you please provide expected result xml? Can you use linq?

Comment: Where do you want to insert the node in your example xml? Before/after the first, second or third occurance?

Comment: I need to insert First node in between Second and Third

Comment: You can use positional xpath expression `/TestCase/TestModule[1]` to access nodes in document order, it's 1-relative.  You cannot otherwise access a node uniquely if there's no unique combination of attributes to select on!

Comment: @John those nodes are totally same. Nothing will change if you'll switch order. Why would you do that?

Comment: I need that functionalty to achive Drag Drop operation..When i drag get node by using UID and Target also get by UID

Answer (score 0):

l_NodeToAppend will be the first by UID.
Selecting the last of the same UIDs is good for you?

```
XmlNode l_targetNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//TestModule[@UID='{0}'][last()]", e.TargetModel.Attributes["UID"].Value));
```

Comment: if the node that have to select is in between

Comment: You can replace 'last()' with any number N but be sure to have Nth element.